# Atmel S21 RTC-calender clock restore after backup

Tags: calendar, clock, atmel

Hello friends of the atmel family,
I have set the clock calender(MODE2) on the current time and date, but everytime I wake up after an period from the backup Mode, I loose  my date and time.
I use as clock source the RTC_CLOCK_SELECTION_ULP1K.
Is there any chance that the clock has still the information after the backup mode

i tried to exclude the reset in the init function and searched in the power.h file for a function to disable the reset of the clock

Comment: I have found the problem. If the Atmel µC starts from backup, it loses the address  to the RTC. You need to set the (RTC) APB Base Address again.